# Parameterize AWS DynamoDB DocumentClient scan params? Combine results of multiple scans?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have to run the same scan across 4 different tables in DynamoDB.

I currently have this code to execute the scan from AWS lambda (and it works for a single table):

```
var params = {
    TableName: "some-table-1",

    ProjectionExpression: "#state, #type",
    FilterExpression: "#state = :state and #type = :type",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#state": "state",
        "#type": "type"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":state": 'Running',
         ":sessionType": 'SomeType'
    }
};
docClient.scan(params, onScan); //onScan function defined somewhere else that writes a metric for # of items meeting this critera
```

General improvements would also be appreciated! (Note: state and sessionType are NOT the primary key or sort key)

I just want to be able to run the scan and send a whole list of tables to get results from, and then process the results of all tables at once.

So for example, I want to get all the items with state = Running and sessionType = SomeType across all 4 tables and return the total across all 4 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Running scan to get the count is not recommended with NoSQL databases. You can maintain a separate atomic counter that maintains the total value.

If you still want to scan and get the totals,

We use ODM, https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels

which can scan repetitively and get the whole set of records.

Eg.,

```
Account
  .scan()
  .loadAll()
  .exec(callback);
```

Hope it helps.